# Is it appropriate to use two "of"s in quick succession?

Tags: prepositions, repetition

Is it appropriate to use two "of"s in quick succession?

For example in this phrase:

> Creation of library of gas turbine components in MATLAB/SIMULINK

Is there a better way of phrasing this?

Note: Substituting "creation" with "creating" is not desirable here

Edit for more context: The phrase is the title for my diploma thesis

Comment: More context for the usage would be helpful.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Edited

Comment: You are missing an article: "Creation of **a** library...". For software libraries you can use "*for*" instead of "*of*" if it's used to mean a codebase and not a collection of data. You can then rephrase the title as "*Creation of a library for gas turbine components in MATLAB/SIMULINK*" or "*Creation of a gas turbine component library in MATLAB/SIMULINK*"

Comment: As @dubious points out, ***for*** is a better preposition than ***of*** for the second context. But that just means it's a poor example context. And as a general rule, there's absolutely nothing "unusual", "incorrect", or "awkward" about sequences like [*the son **of** the sister **of***...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22son+of+the+sister+of%22), so it's misleading to suggest that it should be rephrased for the sake of "style"

Comment: The preposition "to" also may be used multiple times in a sentence, e.g., "I gave the book to Tom to give to his sister to study." Two "to's" in infinitives, two "to's" as prepositions. If I were *writing*, I'd try to phrase it differently, but we often spek a bit repetitiously. BTW, there are even tutus, in ballet.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's grammatically acceptable to repeat words, nevertheless you might make the decision to avoid it for aesthetic reasons.

---

In the following examples, () represents optional words, while slashes such as "of/for" are "alternatives".

On a CV or resume, you could write:

> Created gas turbine components library/libraries in MATLAB/SIMULINK

If a title of a school paper:

> (New) MATLAB/SIMULINK gas turbine components library/libraries

> A (new) library of/for gas turbine components, created in MATLAB/SIMULINK

> A (new) MATLAB/SIMULINK library of/for gas turbine components